# what is the etymology of the word "none-so-pretty"?

Tags: etymology

Merriam Webster defines the word as:

1

a decorative braid or tape used in the late 18th century

2

a : london pride

b : lobel's catchfly

It looks like an interesting word to know but very little information is available online. Also, there is no mention of its origin neither on Online Etymology Dictionary nor any other sites.

Answer (score 1):

The **etymology** of *none-so-pretty* is exactly what it seems:

> Etymology:  < **none** *pron.* + **so** *adv. and conj.* + **pretty** *adj.*
>
> [OED]

It means that there is **nothing as pretty.**

OED does have some historical references. The first references are three or four hundred years ago, but all the meanings survived until the late twentieth century and probably beyond.

> **1.**
>   **a.** A type of fabric used in dressmaking and furnishing, prob. a worsted or lightish stuff. Now *hist.* and *rare.*
>
> > 1622–3   in L. M. Cooper *Rec. Early Eng. Drama: Chester* (1979) 346   Two ounces of Silke one yard and ahalf of None so prettir to make a new Auntient.
>
> **b.** Chiefly *N. Amer.* A kind of decorative haberdashery tape (more fully ***none-so-pretty tape***), often woven in two colours or patterned with simple motifs, and typically used to dress furnishings. Now *hist.* and *rare.*
>
> > c1700   in *N. & Q.* **10** 88/1   Webb-Cane and Leather Hooping, Gartering of all Sorts, Nonesopretties, Pins and Needles, Inkle and Spinnel.
>
> **2.** Any of several garden flowers, *esp.  (a)* London pride, *Saxifraga × urbium* (now *rare*);  (b) heartsease, *Viola tricolor;*  (c) sweet william catchfly, *Silene armeria.* Cf. **nancy-pretty** *n.*   Now chiefly *N. Amer.*
>
> > 1731   P. Miller *Gardeners Dict.* I. at Geum,   London Pride, or None so Pretty.